# Cannot sign in to my organization Mail by Google using Inbox

Tags: inbox-by-gmail, google-workspace-for-business

The only message I get is this:

> Your organization isn't set up for inbox yet

But there the link of "Learn more" doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For G Suite, formerly known as Google Apps, your company has to enable Inbox before you can use it. You would need to contact your organization's G Suite admin and ask them to follow the steps in this article: [Turn Inbox by Gmail on or off](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6082718)